# Need help in grouping and transposing data using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, transpose, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0, exslt

I need help in conditional grouping and transposing XML data.

1. I need to group and transpose data using week of the month, Worker ID and        Rate_Category_Code. Need to report the Hours_Worked in the appropriate weeks. Hours would be blank for all other week. Data in XML will be never for more then a month.
2. If there are overtime hours reported (Identified by Rate_Category_Code as OT) then i need to create separate row for the week in which overtime hours was reported.

Below is the XML data -

``

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT1120_CR_HR_Fieldglass_Daily_Timesheet">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_ID>FNRAWK00001743</wd:Worker_ID>
        <wd:Task_Code>01</wd:Task_Code>
        <wd:GL_Account_Code>Default</wd:GL_Account_Code>
        <wd:Rate_Category_Code>ST</wd:Rate_Category_Code>
        <wd:UOM>HR</wd:UOM>
        <wd:Hours_Worked>8</wd:Hours_Worked>
        <wd:Reported_Date>2019-06-10</wd:Reported_Date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_ID>FNRAWK00001743</wd:Worker_ID>
        <wd:Task_Code>01</wd:Task_Code>
        <wd:GL_Account_Code>Default</wd:GL_Account_Code>
        <wd:Rate_Category_Code>ST</wd:Rate_Category_Code>
        <wd:UOM>HR</wd:UOM>
        <wd:Hours_Worked>8</wd:Hours_Worked>
        <wd:Reported_Date>2019-06-18</wd:Reported_Date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_ID>FNRAWK00001743</wd:Worker_ID>
        <wd:Task_Code>01</wd:Task_Code>
        <wd:GL_Account_Code>Default</wd:GL_Account_Code>
        <wd:Rate_Category_Code>OT</wd:Rate_Category_Code>
        <wd:UOM>HR</wd:UOM>
        <wd:Hours_Worked>1</wd:Hours_Worked>
        <wd:Reported_Date>2019-06-10</wd:Reported_Date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker_ID>FNRAWK00001742</wd:Worker_ID>
        <wd:Task_Code>01</wd:Task_Code>
        <wd:GL_Account_Code>Default</wd:GL_Account_Code>
        <wd:Rate_Category_Code>ST</wd:Rate_Category_Code>
        <wd:UOM>HR</wd:UOM>
        <wd:Hours_Worked>9</wd:Hours_Worked>
        <wd:Reported_Date>2019-06-20</wd:Reported_Date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

``

Desired output -

``

```
Type=Upload Full Time Sheet with Revision
Transaction=True
Approval Required=True
Messaging Required=False
Language=English (United States)
Number Format=#,##9.99 (Example: 1,234,567.99)
Date Format=MM/DD/YYYY
Submit=FALSE
Buyer=FNRA
Supplier Review=False
Comments=

Worker_ID|Month_Start_Date|First_Monday|Cost_Center_Code|Task_Code|GL_Account_Code|Rate_Category_Code|UOM|Mon_Hrs|Tue_Hrs|Wed_Hrs|Thu_Hrs|Fri_Hrs|Sat_Hrs|Sun_Hrs
FNRAWK00001743|06/01/2019|05/27/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001743|06/01/2019|06/03/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001743|06/01/2019|06/10/2019||01|Default|ST|HR|8|||||||
FNRAWK00001743|06/01/2019|06/10/2019||01|Default|OT|HR|1|||||||
FNRAWK00001743|06/01/2019|06/17/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||8||||||
FNRAWK00001743|06/01/2019|06/24/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001742|06/01/2019|05/27/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001742|06/01/2019|06/03/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001742|06/01/2019|06/10/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001742|06/01/2019|06/10/2019||01|Default|OT|HR||||||||
FNRAWK00001742|06/01/2019|06/17/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||9||||
FNRAWK00001742|06/01/2019|06/24/2019||01|Default|ST|HR||||||||
```

``

XSLT -

``

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT1120_CR_HR_Fieldglass_Daily_Timesheet" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" exclude-result-prefixes="xs my functx">
        <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Linefeed" select="'&#13;&#10;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Delimiter" select=" '|' "/>
        <xsl:function name="functx:repeat-string" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:param name="stringToRepeat" as="xs:string?"/>
            <xsl:param name="count" as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="string-join((for $i in 1 to $count return $stringToRepeat),'')"/>
        </xsl:function>
        <xsl:function name="functx:pad-integer-to-length" as="xs:string">
            <xsl:param name="integerToPad" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>
            <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="if ($length &lt; string-length(string($integerToPad))) then error(xs:QName('functx:Integer_Longer_Than_Length')) else concat (functx:repeat-string('0',$length - string-length(string($integerToPad))),string($integerToPad))"/>
        </xsl:function>
        <xsl:function name="functx:date" as="xs:date">
            <xsl:param name="year" as="xs:anyAtomicType"/>
            <xsl:param name="month" as="xs:anyAtomicType"/>
            <xsl:param name="day" as="xs:anyAtomicType"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(concat(functx:pad-integer-to-length(xs:integer($year),4),'-',functx:pad-integer-to-length(xs:integer($month),2),'-',functx:pad-integer-to-length(xs:integer($day),2)))"/>
        </xsl:function>
        <!--Function which accepts date as input and returns the date for first day of the month (Input Date)-->
        <xsl:function name="functx:first-day-of-month" as="xs:date?">
            <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:anyAtomicType?"/>
            <xsl:sequence select="functx:date(year-from-date(xs:date($date)),month-from-date(xs:date($date)),1)"/>
        </xsl:function>
        <!--Function which accepts date as input and returns the date for first day of the week-->
        <xsl:function name="my:thisMonday">
            <xsl:param name="date"/>
            <xsl:variable name="epoch" select="xs:date('0001-01-01')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dayNumber" select="fn:days-from-duration($date - $epoch)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dayOfWeek" select="$dayNumber mod 7"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$date - xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P', $dayOfWeek, 'D' ))"/>
        </xsl:function>
        <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
            <File>
                <Header>
                    <xsl:text>Type=Upload Full Time Sheet with Revision</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Transaction=True</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Approval Required=True</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Messaging Required=False</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Language=English (United States)</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Number Format=#,##9.99 (Example: 1,234,567.99)</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Date Format=MM/DD/YYYY</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Submit=FALSE</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Buyer=FNRA</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Supplier Review=False</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                    <xsl:text>Comments=</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                </Header>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                <Header>
                    <xsl:text>Worker_ID|Date|Week_Start_Date|Cost_Center_Code|Task_Code|GL_Account_Code|Rate_Category_Code|UOM|Mon_Hrs|Tue_Hrs|Wed_Hrs|Thu_Hrs|Fri_Hrs|Sat_Hrs|Sun_Hrs</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
                </Header>
                <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
                    <xsl:call-template name="Write_Rows"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </File>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="Write_Rows">
            <Record>
                <Worker_ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker_ID"/>
                </Worker_ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Date>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(wd:Date,6, 2),'/',substring(wd:Date, 9, 2),'/',substring(wd:Date, 1, 4))"/>-->
                    <!--Pass date in YYYY-MM-DD format to custom function and format the return value to 'MM/DD/YYYY'-->
                    <xsl:variable name="StartDateOfMonth" select="string(functx:first-day-of-month(xs:date(concat(substring(wd:Reported_Date, 1, 4),'-', substring(wd:Reported_Date,6, 2),'-',substring(wd:Reported_Date, 9, 2)))))"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($StartDateOfMonth,6,2),'/',substring($StartDateOfMonth,9,2),'/',substring($StartDateOfMonth,1,4))"/>
                </Date>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Week_Start_Date>
                    <!--<xsl:variable name="WeekStartDate" select="my:thisMonday(xs:date('2019-06-01'))"/>-->
                    <!--Format the return value to 'MM/DD/YYYY'-->
                    <xsl:variable name="WeekStartDate" select="my:thisMonday(xs:date(wd:Reported_Date))"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($WeekStartDate,6,2),'/',substring($WeekStartDate,9,2),'/',substring($WeekStartDate,1,4))"/>
                </Week_Start_Date>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Cost_Center_Code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Cost_Center_Code"/>
                </Cost_Center_Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Task_Code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Task_Code"/>
                </Task_Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <GL_Account_Code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:GL_Account_Code"/>
                </GL_Account_Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Rate_Category_Code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Rate_Category_Code"/>
                </Rate_Category_Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <UOM>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:UOM"/>
                </UOM>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Hours_Worked>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Hours_Worked"/>
                </Hours_Worked>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Delimiter"/>
                <Overtime>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Overtime"/>
                </Overtime>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Linefeed"/>
            </Record>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the task is grouping with a composite key e.g. in XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" composite="yes" group-by="wd:Worker_ID, wd:Rate_Category_Code, my:thisMonday(xs:date(wd:Reported_Date))">
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/wd:Hours_Worked)" separator="|"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

That gives the existing data:

```
FNRAWK00001743|ST|2019-06-10|8
FNRAWK00001743|ST|2019-06-17|8
FNRAWK00001743|OT|2019-06-10|1
FNRAWK00001742|ST|2019-06-17|9
```

You will need to add logic for outputting empty lines for weeks for which there is no data.

Comment: Thank You Martin. This is helpful. Can you give some ideas about how do we write rows where there is no data for the entire week or within the week, hours are missing for some days ? Because data wont be available for these in the XML. Is there a way where i can manipulate my current XML somehow to add remaining days for the months for each worker with 0 hours. Then i can use your above logic to  generate the output in the pattern i need.  I am new to XSLT therefore some starting points would really help.

Comment: @XYZ, compute the Mondays you are interested along the lines of `<xsl:variable name="first-day-of-month" select="my:first-day-of-month(Report_Entry[1]/Reported_Date)"/><xsl:variable name="mondays" as="xs:date*" select="(0 to 4) ! my:thisMonday($first-day-of-month + xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D') * .)"/>`, then fill up the data, either before or after grouping. It is always a bit tedious as you need to process the `$mondays` with `for-each` or `iterate` or `apply-templates` and have the other data as a parameter or variable to merge them but it is mainly a task of filling in the blanks.

Comment: I dont think i completely understand this but thats just my inexperience. I will try out the suggestions you provided and coupe of other things and ask new question if i face issues. Thank you for your help.